# Blur Video background using HTML5 video and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, html5-video

Any suggestion on how can I apply such effect?
Using drawImage method on canvas element doesn't work for me because Safari IOS doesn't support video element as a source for drawImage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add two video elements - one on top of the other. The bottom one zoomed to fill and with a CSS blur filter applied, the top one scaled to fit with no blur.

```css
#fg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}

#bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur(20px);
}

div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div>

<video id="bg" width="400" autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>

<video id="fg" width="200" autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>

</div>
```

Comment: I thought about this as well, but having two videos playing at the same time would affect the performance on mobile. As it is stream service application. I was able to do it using canvas, but unfortunately Safari IOS doesn't support canvas method imageDraw: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/canvasrenderingcontext2d/1630282-drawimage

Comment: @RenatoGuimaraesNunes it would, but not loads and they should be able to share the source - you're not downloading the image twice, you're just processing it twice, bit you're going to have to do that to blur it anyway (whether frame by frame in a canvas or as two video elements).